# XSL Transformation - Keys from first xml to second xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

from 2 xml files I am looking to produce a new xml file. Please note 4103700 and 4103701 are the keys from the first xml. Based on that I need to pick the values from second xml.

First XML file:

```
<B2BXo856ShipmentCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/dbService">
        <B2BXo856Shipment>
            <shipPk>3165760</shipPk>
            <customerNumber>250117</customerNumber>
            <shipperNumber>188884001</shipperNumber>
            <b2BXo856CartonCollection>
                <B2BXo856Carton>
                    <cartonPk>4103700</cartonPk>
                    <numberOfBoxes>6</numberOfBoxes>
                    <cartonWeight>4</cartonWeight>
                </B2BXo856Carton>
                <B2BXo856Carton>
                    <cartonPk>4103701</cartonPk>
                    <numberOfBoxes>6</numberOfBoxes>
                    <cartonWeight>4</cartonWeight>
                </B2BXo856Carton>
            </b2BXo856CartonCollection>
        </B2BXo856Shipment>
    </B2BXo856ShipmentCollection>
```

Second XML file:

```
<dbReferenceOutputCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/dbReference">
    <dbReferenceOutput>
        <carton_fk>4103700</carton_fk>
        <date_code>1701</date_code>
        <SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>100</SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>
    </dbReferenceOutput>
    <dbReferenceOutput>
        <carton_fk>4103700</carton_fk>
        <date_code>1705</date_code>
        <SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>800</SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>
    </dbReferenceOutput>
    <dbReferenceOutput>
        <carton_fk>4103701</carton_fk>
        <date_code>1703</date_code>
        <SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>130</SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>
    </dbReferenceOutput>
    <dbReferenceOutput>
        <carton_fk>4103701</carton_fk>
        <date_code>1707</date_code>
        <SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>500</SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>
    </dbReferenceOutput>
    <dbReferenceOutput>
        <carton_fk>4103701</carton_fk>
        <date_code>1710</date_code>
        <SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>500</SUM_NUMBER_PARTS_PER_BOX_>
    </dbReferenceOutput>
</dbReferenceOutputCollection>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<tns:Pip3B2AdvanceShipmentNotification xmlns:tns="http://www.edifecs.com/RosettaNet/100">
    <tns:AdvancedShipmentNotification>
        <tns:Shipment>
            <tns:ShippingContainer>
                <tns:LinearPhysicalDimension>
                    <tns:GlobalPhysicalUnitOfMeasureCode>4103700</tns:GlobalPhysicalUnitOfMeasureCode>
                </tns:LinearPhysicalDimension>
                <tns:ShippingContainerItem>
                    <tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                        <tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>1701</tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>
                    </tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                    <tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                        <tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>1705</tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>
                    </tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                </tns:ShippingContainerItem>
            </tns:ShippingContainer>
            <tns:ShippingContainer>
                <tns:LinearPhysicalDimension>
                    <tns:GlobalPhysicalUnitOfMeasureCode>4103701</tns:GlobalPhysicalUnitOfMeasureCode>
                </tns:LinearPhysicalDimension>
                <tns:ShippingContainerItem>
                    <tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                        <tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>1703</tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>
                    </tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                    <tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                        <tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>1707</tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>
                    </tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                    <tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                        <tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>1710</tns:GlobalDocumentReferenceTypeCode>
                    </tns:DocumentSubLineLotShipReference>
                </tns:ShippingContainerItem>
            </tns:ShippingContainer>
        </tns:Shipment>
    </tns:AdvancedShipmentNotification>
</tns:Pip3B2AdvanceShipmentNotification>
```

For the first key there are 2 values in the second xml and for the second key there are 3 values.

Any help or pointers appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Here's a pointer: Use a programming language to solve your problem. This often leads to useful results. When you have a question with a certain aspect your solution, you are welcome to ask it here. However, *"I have X and I need Y"* is not a question.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758481/how-to-use-two-or-more-xml-files-in-one-xsl-document has some information on processing multiple files.

Comment: There is a significant difference between XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 in the way keys work across documents. Please clarify which XSLT processor will you be using. Also post the expected output.

Comment: HI Michael, I am looking for a solution preferebly in 1.0 first. The tool I am using supports 1.0. There's round about way of using 2.0. I have pasted the expected output in the question. Please see the 3rd xml.

Comment: @Gerriet - Thanks for the pointer but that didnt help me.

Comment: Here's an example to get you started; http://stackoverflow.com/a/25859743/3016153

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k Somehow no matter what I try, I cant get this thing working :( I tried the post but cant get that working. I will keep on trying anyway.

Comment: @user2351802 Edit your question and post your best attempt, so we can fix it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I managed to get it working in some round about way. First merged the 2 xml files then did the transformation. It worked.

Comment: @michael.hor257k- I would still like to know how to use the key and transform from 2 xml files. I will give it a try later and update the question. Whenever you have time, you can take a look. Thanks