# XML with <code>-elements must be filled with values from extern file using xslt and xsl:import

Tags: xml, xslt, import, xslt-1.0, rtf

i have this example XML-File with `code`-elements which every `code`-Value stands for a country.
The name of the countries are listed in an external XML-File. Later i want to use this external-file in another XML-Files to be more flexible. I want to output the XML-File with the name of the country.

- `<code>1<code>` stands for `Poland`,
- `<code>2<code>` stands for `France`,
- `<code>3<code>` stands for `Egypt`,
- for i.E. `<code>5<code>` that dont exists `Unknown`.

*XML-File countries.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="countries.xsl" ?>
<LandList>
    <Land>
        <code>1</code>
    </Land>
    <Land>
        <code>2</code>
    </Land>
    <Land>
        <code>3</code>
    </Land>
    <Land>
        <code>4</code>
    </Land>
</LandList>
```

*XML-File with code values: countries.xsl*

```
<Codelist>
    <LandCode>
        <code>1</code>
        <name>Poland</name>
    </LandCode>
    <LandCode>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>France</name>
    </LandCode>
    <LandCode>
        <code>3</code>
        <name>Egypt</name>
    </LandCode>
</Codelist>
```

*Expected Output as rtf/text:*

- Poland
- France
- Egypt

OR with more details

- Land: Poland
- Land: France
- Land: Egypt
- Land: unknown (not in list avaiable)

Want to use xslt 1.0 and using xsl:import. Can anyone help me?

*Tried this with XML Notepad:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <!-- Import -->
  <xsl:import href="codelist.xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="LandList/Land/code">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:variable name="currentCode" select="."/>
      <xsl:variable name="countryName" select="/Codelist/LandCode[code = $currentCode]/name"/>
      <xsl:if test="$countryName">
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$countryName"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*The Output in XML Notepad are:*
**Error Transforming XML**

Thank you. Tom

Comment: `xsl:import` is intended for importing XSLT stylesheets. Use the `document()` function to access XML documents other that the one being processed.

Comment: See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859743/3016153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsl:import` is used to import XSLT fragments. You are looking to load an XML document, which you can do with the `document()` function, and assign that to an `xsl:variable`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    
    <!-- Import -->
    <xsl:variable name="codelist" select="document('codelist.xml')"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="LandList/Land/code">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="currentCode" select="."/>
            <xsl:variable name="countryName" select="$codelist/Codelist/LandCode[code = $currentCode]/name"/>
            <xsl:if test="$countryName">
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$countryName"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```